# GWT ClientBundle not finding image

Tags: gwt

I have created a ClientBundle as below.

```
public interface DataResources extends ClientBundle {
    DataResources IMPL = (DataResources) GWT.create(DataResources.class);
            @Source("marker.png")
            ImageResource markerimage();

            @Source("settings.png")
            ImageResource settingsimage();

            @Source("back.png")
            ImageResource backimage();
}
```

I am getting an error that it cannot find the resources. I have all the images in the top level of my "war" directory.

```
00:00:04.302  [ERROR] Resource marker.png not found. Is the name specified as Class.getResource() would expect?
```

Comment: I think that data resources are referenced relative to the package (folder) your class is in. Try moving the images in the same package to check if that works. I typically place them in something like com.project.resources.images. This way they get included in jars and you can use them in other projects too!

Comment: Hi filip-klu. Yes that got it working. If you want to put that as your answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data resources are referenced relative to the package (folder) your class is in. You can try moving the images in the same package to check if that works.

I would typically have my resource interface in a package - something like `com.project.resources`. The images would then be in `com.project.resources.images`, and the Source annotations would take the form  `@Source("/images/marker.png")`.

By following this package structure you can also bundle your resources/images in JARs and can include and reference them in other projects.